# Which Git GUI can show list of files inside stash?

Tags: 14.04, gui, git

It was very easy in [Sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) but this tool is not available on Linux

Answer (score 10):

gitk shows the content of your stash:

```
$ gitk --all&
```

Since both the index and the working tree are saved in stash, you see both, and the diff looks a bit different than what you might be used to.

---

```
$ git stash show -p
```

shows the stash content on the command line. If you have several stashes, you can specify the stash name, e.g. `stash@{3}`.

Comment: menu view->everything shows the stashes also.

Comment: This is not working: on my repository, this shows only the last entry, and in the middle of thousands of other non-stash entries, so this would take me hour to find out it out if I do not know in advance the exact name of the commit. It is not even possible to filter the entries with "stash" keyword

Comment: @calandoa: I assumed the stash was recent and in the vicinity of the checked out commit. See if my edit better fits your need.

Comment: @calandoa: You can find the latest stash easily using "File" > "List references" > Click "stash".

Comment: @calandoa: The possibility of showing all the stashes instead of just the last [stash] entry is being studied [link](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=148153538526352&w=2), [backup link](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg291763.html); if you really thrive at it you can even apply a patch yourself using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/uprego/d8c3c059c56ebb911974bb905157a81e). Apologies the state is kind of early alpha, but it mostly would work OK.

Comment: See also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573623/is-it-possible-to-preview-stash-contents-in-git/23893369#comment62874363_23893369](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573623/is-it-possible-to-preview-stash-contents-in-git/23893369#comment62874363_23893369) about multiple stashes in `gitk`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried several GUIs without success, though I may have missed some options:

- gitk (check my comment in the other answer)
- git gui
- giggle
- gitkraken

The ones which worked fine:

- gitg (show the stash by default at the top of other commits)
- tig with "tig stash" (text UI but very handy)

Comment: It's tricky now, but if in huge need `gitk` can be tweaked to show all stashes, see the comment history of [the other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/487463/203967).

Comment: See also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573623/is-it-possible-to-preview-stash-contents-in-git/23893369#comment62874363_23893369](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573623/is-it-possible-to-preview-stash-contents-in-git/23893369#comment62874363_23893369) about multiple stashes in `gitk`.

Answer (score 1):

[Git Cola](https://git-cola.github.io/) has a dedicated stash viewer (<kbd>Alt+Shift+S</kbd> by default).